# Cannot resolve promise from axios response on client side

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios

I am doing an api request to my express backend via axios in my action creators.
I can see the request logged on the backend (but without a status) and successfully going through, but the response never returns to the front end (I do not see the LOGIN_SUCCESS output in the browser console).
When I simulate the same request on curl locally, it works just fine and returns 200 with the message.

Frontend:

./actions/index.js

```
const loginRequested = function () {
    console.log(LOGIN_REQUESTED)
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUESTED,
        loading: true,
    }
}

const loginSuccess = function () {
    console.log(LOGIN_SUCCESS)
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        isAuthUser: true,
    }
}

export const login = ({ email, password }) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loginRequested());

        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/login', {
            username: email,
            password: password,
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('This has been reached')
            dispatch(loginSuccess(response));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('An error took place: ', err)
        })
    }
}
```

Login component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { login } from './actions/index'
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
        this.setEmail = this.setEmail.bind(this);
        this.setPassword = this.setPassword.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        this.props.login({
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        })
    }

    setEmail(e) {
        this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    }

    setPassword(e) {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form className="Form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        autoFocus
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        onChange={this.setEmail}
                    />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                    </Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        onChange={this.setPassword}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember Password" />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: user => {
            dispatch(login(user));
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthUser: state.isAuthUser,
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

I am also using redux-thunk to support async operations:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Backend:

app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var homeRouter = require('./routes/home')
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');
var registerRouter = require('./routes/register')
var db = require('./repositories/db');
var app = express();

// Connect to DB
require('./repositories/db')

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/home', homeRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/register', registerRouter)
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/login.js:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.username }).then(
        (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: new Error('User not found!')
                });
            }
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password).then(
                (valid) => {
                    username = req.body.username;
                    if (!valid) {
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            error: new Error('Incorrect password!')
                        });
                    }
                    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, jwtKey, {
                        algorithm: 'HS256',
                        expiresIn: jwtExpirySeconds,
                    });
                    console.log('User successfully logged in.');
                    res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: jwtExpirySeconds * 1000 });
                    res.send({ message: 'We did it!' })
                }
            ).catch(
                (err) => {
                    console.log('Error logging in: ', err);
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    ).catch(
        (err) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Request from curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "username": "a@a.com",
    "password": "qwer1234"
}' -v -i 'http://localhost:9000/login'
```

Output from curl:

```
User successfully logged in.
POST /login 200 61.225 ms - 24
```

Output from programmatic API request above:

```
POST /login - - ms - -
User successfully logged in.
```

Comment: Async stuff inside actions isn't supported out of the box with Redux. You need a tool like `redux-thunk`

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I am using redux-thunk, will include more snippets

Comment: Can you show the relevant `mapDispatchToProps` for the `login` function in whatever component you're passing it to

Comment: Updated with the component. I know the mapDispatchToProps does work because I can see the LOGIN_REQUEST logged in the console.

Comment: In the app you send login request to "/login" but your backend handles POST requests on "/". Are you sure when you test via curl you're submitting the same request as the app?

Comment: Yea sorry I did not include all the code but that code is used in the main app.js file: var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', loginRouter);

Comment: @Ralph You can try setting up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for your dev environment so cors will not cause problems.